# How to cut a String in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have that string ...

```
C:\Users\ApplicationData\Folder1\Myapp.exe
```

How could i cut like:

```
C:\Users\ApplicationData\Folder1
```

I have tried `s.split("\Myapp.exe")` , where `s` is `C:\Users\ApplicationData\Folder1\Myapp.exe`

Plase help me, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Path` class:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\Users\ApplicationData\Folder1\Myapp.exe")
```

Check it here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

Comment: @Meta-Knight Thanks, I didn't know that, I've been out of VB.NET for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class.

 It contains a function FullName, which returns the directory full name.
check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx)